# Calculate the polarization vector on reflection or refraction from a dielectric interface

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

I am interested in ray-tracing polarized photons. I have code that works very well for unpolarized light. When a ray hits a dielectric interface the photon is either reflected or refracted by comparing the Fresnel coefficients with a random number.

The calculation of the reflected or refracted direction vector is relatively simple. Say we have a direction vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ and surface normal to the dielectric interface $\boldsymbol{n}$.

**Reflected direction vector**

$$
  \boldsymbol{v} - 2d\boldsymbol{n}
  $$

**Refracted direction vector**

$$
  N\boldsymbol{v} + (Nd - c) \boldsymbol{n}
  $$

In the above $d=\left(\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}\right)$, $N=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ which is the ratio of the refraction index at the interface, and $c =\left(1 - N^2\left(1 - d^2\right)\right)^{1/2}$. These transformation are easily applied within the ray tracing loop because call values are known.

**Question**

My question is what transformation needs to be applied to calculate the correct polarisation vector of a reflected or refracted ray? Before hitting the interface the polaristaion vector of the ray $\boldsymbol{k}$ is known (I assume linear polarised states only). Clearly $\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}=0$, but where in the plane perpendicular to the direction vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ does the polaristaion vector $\boldsymbol{k}$ lie? Can I apply a simple transformation, similar to the above, to find the new polaristaion vector?

Comment: I actually do this somewhere in a code I wrote about ten years ago. I shall have a look at it and get back to you if no one else answers, but I'm pretty sure that I just brute force it: my ray objects carry also polarization vectors, one resolves into $s$ and $p$, applies the Fresnel equations and reassembles the new rays. I don't think I found any particular elegant transformations for this. The Fresnel equations, being so nonlinear, would seem to rule out a simple solution like you're susggesting. What's the grey square BTW?

Comment: Well it is grey only on stackoverflow :) Thanks for the offer. So rather than have one *vector* transformation, you recommend transforming the components. But actually I still don't understand exactly how to do that, how do you determine the reflection polarisation vector for  TE and TM components?

Answer (score 2):

You have separate [Fresnel equations](http://www.teknik.uu.se/ftf/education/ftf2/Optics_FresnelsEqns.pdf) for [s- and p-polarized light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_%28waves%29#S_and_P_Polarization). The two polarizations reflect/refract separately. You can reconstitute them on the other side to recover the new polarization vector if you want.

Comment: I can decompose into *s* and *p* components by calculating the plane of incidence for the ray. In the above is $\bf{k}$ the polarisation vector (normally $\bf{k}$ mean direction). What is the meaning the $\bf{n}$ terms?

Comment: Yes, that's what you are supposed to do. What I wrote was crap :)

Comment: I realize now this is essentially WetSavannaAnimal's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The only part that needs to change is "the photon is either reflected or refracted by comparing the Fresnel coefficients with a random number."

If you know both the polarization and the phase, you can calculate whether to reflect or refract.  No longer does the number need to be random.

Comment: Isn't reflection from an interface was inherently probabilistic? In any case, the Monte-Carlo method requires that one can calculate a probability (this is where the reflection coefficients are used, and I can do this easily for unpolarised or polarised photons) and compared with a random number. The result determine the next path of the photon and the direction vector gets transformed accordingly. Where I am stuck is on how to transform the polarisation vector.

Comment: Probabilistic if you dont know the phase. Depending of the phase of the photon, it has a higher or lower chance of begin reflected or refracted.

Comment: I didn't know that, do you have a reference I can follow?

Comment: I like the description about 7:45 of [Feynman_youtube lecture_on_light](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUAG3yDInQQ&feature=youtu.be) where Feynman talks about something that 'follows the particle along changing its disposition to do things' - ie, it reflects or refracts depending on the phase.

Comment: "Probabilistic if you dont know the phase. Depending of the phase of the photon, it has a higher or lower chance of begin reflected or refracted" -- it is still probabilistic then, isn't it?